# Database Link from Oracle 10g on Windows over to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, oracle, amazon-rds, database-link

Didn't see any answers on this subject so hoping for a miracle! :-)

I've got an Oracle 10g database running on Windows Server 2003 and I'd like to create a database link to an external MySQL database which is running in the Amazon Web Service RDS cloud.

We may have the option of upgrading the Oracle version to 11g if that would help?

Has anyone done anything like this before?

Thanks for your help! Josh

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by conneting to an ODBC data source through a dg4odbc listener.

There is a reasonable explanation available here:

http://hs2n.wordpress.com/2012/04/03/oracle-create-database-link-to-mysql-database/